# how to stop sound on pressing a button

Tags: iphone

I am Using Following code to play sound

```
 NSString *laughSoundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"laugh" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *laughURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:laughSoundPath];
    laughTone = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:laughURL error:nil];
    [laughTone prepareToPlay];
    [laughTone setDelegate:self];
    [laughURL release];

-(IBAction)play
{
[laughTone play];
}
```

i am Using following line to stop sound

```
-(IBAction)stop
    {
    [laughTone stop];
    }
```

Problem is.. When i play sound again, its starting from the point where it was stopped.. i mean to say its working as pause.. help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try resetting the time and then playing, again put the code in your play method:

```
laughTone.currentTime = 0;
[laughTone play];
```

Answer (score 8):

```
-(IBAction)stop
{
    [laughTone stop];
    [laughTone playAtTime:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *Str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ahhh" ofType:@"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer *audioSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ahhhPath] error:NULL];

-(IBAction)btnStopsound(id)sender
{
  [audioSound stop];
  audioSound.currentTime=0;
  [audioSound play];  //restart the player

}
```